# What is the id number for role teacher in moodle 3.8

Tags: sql, moodle

```
SELECT c.fullname, c.shortname, g.name, u.firstname, u.lastname, r.shortname
FROM prefix_course AS c
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra
JOIN prefix_groups AS g ON c.id = g.courseid
JOIN prefix_role AS r
JOIN prefix_user AS u 
WHERE c.groupmode > 0 AND WHERE ra.roleid > 6
```

instead of 6 i want to enter id number of role teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
SELECT c.fullname, c.shortname, g.name, u.firstname, u.lastname, r.shortname
FROM prefix_course AS c
JOIN prefix_context ctx ON ctx.instanceid = c.id AND ctx.contextlevel = 50
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN prefix_groups AS g ON c.id = g.courseid
JOIN prefix_role AS r ON r.id = ra.roleid
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
WHERE c.groupmode > 0 AND r.shortname = 'teacher'
```

Where '50' is the context level for 'course'. This will show all the users who have the role 'teacher' at the course level, giving the name of the teacher, the name of the course and a list of all the groups that exist in the course (there will be a complete row for each group and it will not take into account whether or not the teacher is a member of that group).

Note that this will only include 'Non-editing teachers' in the list, if you wanted both 'Teachers' and 'Non-editing teachers', you would need to change the last line to:

```
WHERE c.groupmode > 0 AND (r.shortname = 'teacher' OR r.shortname = 'editingteacher')
```

Comment: i tried it but it shows the following error.       Query failed
Table 'scisagez_mood676.mdlei_role_context' doesn't exist

Comment: `code SELECT c.fullname, c.shortname, g.name, u.firstname, u.lastname, r.shortname
FROM prefix_course AS c
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra 
JOIN prefix_groups AS g ON c.id = g.courseid
JOIN prefix_role AS r ON r.id = ra.roleid
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
WHERE c.groupmode > 0 AND (r.shortname = 'teacher' OR r.shortname = 'editingteacher') `                                                                               i made a few changes and now it's showing all the users with editingteacher role.

Comment: I fixed the typo in my answer - should have been prefix_context, not prefix_role_context

Comment: If you do not use groups, it wont get the users, you have to make a **LEFT** JOIN on groups :
`LEFT JOIN prefix_groups AS g ON c.id = g.courseid`

Comment: Ludo - it is true that if you are not using groups, you would need to LEFT JOIN the groups table, but as the original question was for a scenario where groups were in use, I don't think this is a relevant change (as an aside, you'd probably also need to remove the 'c.groupmode > 0' part ...)